# Trouble parsing Twitter timestamps using to_timestamp function

Tags: postgresql, twitter, timestamp

I downloaded twitter data over the streaming API and want to get the data into Postgres (version 9.3) to do some geographic analysis.

Parsing the json data works but I can't get the twitter time to a proper timestamp. This is the timestamp from the json:

```
Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0000 2013
```

I tried to parse it this way:

```
select to_timestamp('Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0000 2013', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
```

But it only works if I get rid of the `+0000` part.

It would be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: Tried to toss in TZ in the format argument?

Comment: select to_timestamp('Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0000 2013', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY') tells me that TZ is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, if all times are +0000:

```
test=# select to_timestamp('Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0000 2013', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS +0000 YYYY');
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2013-10-09 10:31:05+02
(1 row)
```

If not, it doesn't seem to matter much:

```
test=# select to_timestamp('Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0200 2013', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS +0000 YYYY');
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2013-10-09 10:31:05+02
(1 row)

test=# select to_timestamp('Wed Oct 09 10:31:05 +0200 2013', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS xxxx YYYY')::timestamp without time zone;
    to_timestamp     
---------------------
 2013-10-09 10:31:05
(1 row)
```